# Angular 2 mentions with primeng p-editor enter to add not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to implement `ng2-mentions` with `primeng` `p-editor` that is working when i type @ list is coming and i can move over list using arrows keys but when i press enter nothing happens. Means selected item is not added in p-editor type area.

Reference links

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-mentions

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor

Comment: PrimeFaces != PrimeNG, correct your tagging please

Comment: @Kukeltje, Please help me out for same if you can

Comment: I don't use PrimeNG, I use PrimeFaces so I'm unable to help. Sorry